# Jasmine: stub an ajax success call and pass the function an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jasmine

I am looking to write a test in Jasmine that expects a string to be displayed in the browser when a button is clicked, that triggers an AJAX call returning a JSON object from an API which then has a function run on it, to extract the required data.

Using the Jasmine Ajax documentation I have come up with the following solution, which is working, but I have noticed a weakness in this test.

```
beforeEach(function(){
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '.';
    loadFixtures('thermostat.html');
  });

describe("displaying weather from open weather map api", function() {

  it("can display current temp for London", function(){
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
    var weatherobject = {"main": {"temp": 12.09}}
    jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather').andReturn({
      success: loaddata(weatherobject)
    });
    $("#London").click();
    expect("#weatherapidata").toContainHtml("12.09");
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
  });
});
```

Below is the javascript and jQuery it is testing. If the function contents, in the success response, of this code, are changed to something other than `loaddata` the tests will still pass, as `loaddata` is also called in the test, as I could not work out how to pass the success function an argument of the `weatherobject` in the test.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#London').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
      data: {
        q:"London",
        units:"metric",
        APPID: weatherapikey
      },
      success: function(data){
        loaddata(data);
      }
    });
  });
});

function loaddata(data) {
  $("#weatherapidata").text(data.main.temp);
};
```

Therefore my question is; is it possible to construct the jasmine test stub to pass the `data` parameter of `function` in the success response an argument of the `weatherobject`?

My thoughts were to pass the object as a string in `responseText`, in the following way

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather').andReturn({
  responseText: weatherobject
});
```

(I also tried `JSON.stringify(weatherobject)` as the responseText callback in this format) but I could not get this to work and hence my above solution was the workaround.

[Github link to this project](https://github.com/RBGeomaticsRob/thermostat)

I have also added to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RobRB/m2u2mwvz/) however at the moment I cannot locate a jasmine-jquery cdn that works with jsfiddle and hence the 'toContainHTML' throws an is not a function error. However the response of the stub can be seen in the line above the button at the top of the HTML.

Comment: @tandrewnichols thanks for the reply, unfortunately I have tried this and '#weatherapidata' when inspected does not receive the text as the function in the ajax success does not receive an object.

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it looks like `jasmine.Ajax` wraps the XMLHttpRequest object. But jquery abstracts that. My guess is that `andReturn({ responseText: weatherobject })` would work, as that's how the example of `stubRequest` returns data: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/ajax.html#section-13

Comment: @tandrewnichols thanks again for your time, this was my thinking on reading the docs as well. Unfortunately the ajax success callback does not receive the object. I will edit the question to reflect this. I'm going to look into how the jquery success callback works to see if this will helps explain.

Comment: If you have the time, you could also build a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so others can try things with the code too.

Comment: @tandrewnichols Thanks, I'll take a look at putting the code up there tomorrow evening, once I work out how to include the jasmine specs in the fiddle. In the meantime the code is all available on [github](https://github.com/RBGeomaticsRob/thermostat)

Answer (score 3):

This [blog](http://a-developer-life.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/jasmine-part-2-spies-and-mocks.html) post guided me towards using a slightly different way of constructing the tests, which works as required by providing the JSON object to the success callback. By spying on the ajax call and then using `mostRecent()` to address the success callback on the `$("London").click()` ajax function and provide it the JSON object. The success callback in the code is able to receive the mock and operate on the object, with the implementation below:

```
it("can send a GET request for weather data", function(){
  spyOn($, 'ajax');
  var weatherobject = {"main" : {"temp" : 12.09}}
  $("#London").click();
  $.ajax.calls.mostRecent().args[0].success(weatherobject);
  expect("#weatherapidata").toContainHtml("12.09")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the ajax stubbing affects the fixture loading process (which also uses ajax).  The suggested solution was to preload the fixtures

https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#mocking-with-jasmine-ajax

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this wasn't required for my solution to the problem in the end but did lead me to thinking more about how the test is working.